# Actual position of app design in graphical versus in Emulator

Tags: android

I am very novice in android platform.I am trying to design an application.For the design purpose i have taken `RelativeLayout` .But the unique thing that i am noticing is while seeing it in graphical Layout in eclipse ,Buttons and EditText are at different position while it is at right position when seeing in emulator.

Here is my code..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pnr_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pnr_normal" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="266dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tenq_normal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/submit" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="6"
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
android:layout_row="6"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />
```

Why is this happening.Will it do any impact on the different size of the mobile screens.
Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's correct thing. Whatever layout/UI you see, it won't be the same in emulator or real device. Reason being is android comes with multiple and variety of resolutions. The layout which you see while designing is just to preview the design or we can say just a sample preview of UI with controls/widgets you have taken.

You can consider it as an advantage of designing UI/layout in android for different resolutions/multiple screens.

When I say advantage, it means you can design just a single layout and can preview it for multiple screens, and so you would be having better idea.

### Update:

Just check the image and do the same thing as depicted in image, to preview all screens. Once again I am repeating, the preview which you are seeing is just a preview, it would looks somewhat different in real devices.

[image]

Comment: Thank u sir !.Will you please give some links where i can get design tutorials where i can design just a single layout and can preview it for multiple screens,

Comment: Thanks once again sir,Will you please tell me why is my <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="6"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />   is displaying at the top of screen..